# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 576000 into shape (90,28,28,1)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

```
# load train and test dataset
def load_dataset():
  # load dataset
  (trainX, trainY)= a.load_dataset()
  (testX, testY) = b.load_dataset()
  print(trainX.shape)
  
  # reshape dataset to have a single channel
  trainX = trainX.reshape((trainX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
  testX = testX.reshape((testX.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
  # one hot encode target values
  trainY = to_categorical(trainY)
  testY = to_categorical(testY)
  
  return trainX, trainY, testX, testY
```

Help me with reshaping array.
My data is in grayscale form. I want it to reshaped in 28x28x1 form to train my model.
Shape of trainX is 90x80x80

Error:

[image: Error showing up]

Comment: You cannot reshape a `90x80x80` tensor into a `??x28x28x1` tensor, since `28 * 28` does not dviide `90 * 80 * 80`. Are you sure about the shape of `trainX`?

Comment: Reshape is not the same as resize, please understand the operations you are using.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki, this is what I know. I want to know that what should I do now.

Comment: It is impossible to do what you wanted, since the numbers of elements do not match. If you want to *resize* (not *reshape*) each input image down from `80 x 80` to `28 x 28`, you need to use functions like [`tf.image.resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize).

Comment: @kotatsuyaki, Got it. So it is all about image size.